# Show information on selected apps when browsing installed apps

Tags: unity

When we browse installed apps, how can we get information on a app without to go in synaptic, apt-get or ubuntu software center.

Need a more info for the selected apps on right click ou on mouse over the selected app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to get information about installed apps without using synaptic or the software center, if I need information about an app, I just google it, and usually, the company/person/team/business that made the app, their website usually is on the first page of google, that's what I do, but if you don't have internet, then i don't know what else to tell you, is it a specific app? or is it that synaptic and the software center don't supply enough information?